# how to style images of different height in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I want to style images of different height. These images are stored in an array. I have used flatlist to show the images.

```
<FlatList 
    data={this.props.category}
    renderItem={({item}) =>{
        Image.getSize(item.imagepath, (srcWidth, srcHeight)=>{
        const maxHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
        const maxWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
        const ratio = Math.min(maxWidth / srcWidth, maxHeight / srcHeight);
        this.setState({width:srcWidth*ratio, height:srcHeight*ratio})
        })  
        return(
           <View>
           { this.state.width && this.state.height ?( 
               <Card style={styles.fullCard}>
               <Image 
                   source={{uri:item.imagepath}} 
                   style={{width:this.state.width, height:this.state.height}} 
                 />
                </Card>):(null)
            }
            </View>
            )
        }
    }
/>
```

I want these images according to their length. It should auto adjust itself.

Comment: Take a look at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#aspectratio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me using react-native-auto-height-image plugin. It takes the full height by itself. Only problem it created was for width.

```
<FlatList 
    data={props.category}
    renderItem={({item}) =>{
        const maxWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
        return(
            <Card style={styles.fullCard}>
            <AutoHeightImage source={{uri:item.imagepath}} width={maxWidth-20}/>
            </Card>
        )
        }
    }
/>
```

I solved issue of width using the dimesions of the device.